# Unable to Add, Edit, or Remove users and groups for Enterprise Application

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azureportal

I've created and registered a web application via Azure Active Directory -> App Registrations.

Within my application manifest I've created a role (why there's no UI to do this is beyond me), and for now am planning on adding quite a few more.

However, I'm unable to assign users to the role I created via Azure Active Directory -> Enterprise Applications, as the Add, Edit, and Remove options are greyed out.

According to [these docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-coreapps-assign-user-azure-portal), I need to be Global Admin to be able to set these.  The only way I can do so is to keep pestering my network admin every time I want to assign users/groups to roles.  This is obviously not a suitable solution, and as the registered application owner, it should be trivial for me to control the authorization levels of my application.

How is it possible for me to assign users & groups to the roles I create?  If it's simply not possible without having to raise the issue with my global admin, what are my options?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly, as per docs, you already went through, today only administrator can assign roles to an application.

There is [a feature request](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/10232130-allow-application-owners-to-assign-users-without-g) to simplify that and Microsoft is working on a solution. If you [give your vote](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/10232130-allow-application-owners-to-assign-users-without-g), it will certainly make the request more important.

For time being it is only the Global Admin who can grant permissions to an Application.

Comment: Thanks!  I've voted on it.  For now, I've been given temporary global admin access.

Comment: You can work out with your Azure AD Admin to use [Privileged Identity Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-privileged-identity-management-configure?toc=%2fazure%2factive-directory%2fprivileged-identity-management%2ftoc.json) for time being - but it requires Azure AD P2 License.